# difference between variables in typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript

What does this mean in Typescript.
**"!option"** and **"option"** aren't the same???

```
const limit = !options.limit || options.limit === NaN ? 0 : options.limit
```

Comment: If this is used in an `if` condition, it is pointless. If this expression is being assigned to a variable, it will  returns `true` if `options.limit` is falsy. It will return `option.limit`, if it is truthy

Comment: both are different and opposite to each one not operator (!variable) and one is directly value.

Comment: `!` is negation of anything that `options.limit` is ..

Comment: Also there are no types in what you've shown, it's just JS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Regarding your updated code:

```
const limit = !options.limit || options.limit === NaN ? 0 : options.limit
```

- If `options.limit` is [`falsy`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Falsy), this will set `limit = 0`. Else, it will use `options.limit`
- The second condition is not required because `NaN` is a falsy value. It is already covered in `!options.limit` condition.
- Also, `options.limit === NaN` is never true, not even if `options.limit` is `NaN`. You need to use [`isNaN()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/isNaN) or [`Number.isNaN()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/isNaN) to check for `NaN`

Your current code is equivalent to:

```
const limit = options.limit || 0.
```

Comment: what is the difference between ?? and || then? i can write it as const limit = options.limit ?? 0 right?

Comment: @grooot `??` only checks for null and undefeined. `||` checks for all [falsy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Falsy) values: null, undefined, `""`, false, 0, NaN

Comment: @grooot why do have the condition `=== NaN` in your code? Just want to know the possible values for `options.limit`. Do you get numbers in string format like `"50"`?